# How to search in unicode using FindWindow in C++

Tags: c++, unicode

I am stuck about searching for a Chinese program name while using `FindWindowW(NULL, "program name")` function.

When I searched for English, it works perfectly.

Can someone give me a clue about how to search using a unicode?

I couldn't figure out yet, can someone guide me how to do?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowW(NULL,L"\uAA5A\uAA4C\uB873\uAB4C\uB6C7");

    if(NULL == hWnd){
        printf("NotFound!");
    }else {
        printf("Found!");
    }
   }
```

Comment: `FindWindowW`...

Comment: When you build your program, have you defined the `UNICODE` macro? That will cause the `FindWindow` "call" to be a call to [`FindWindowW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww). But don't forget to use wide-character strings, as in `L"program name"` (or one of the Windows macros like `TEXT("program name")`)

Comment: even with this simple program

#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"test\n \x263a");
}

i can't print it out the smiley face properly...

bythe way i using codeblock, is that matter?

Comment: @nelLuffy that is a completely different question not related to this FindWindow question.

Comment: @nelLuffy Your simple program is correct.  You just need a terminal font that supports the character.  You'll find that if you cut-and-paste the output (probably a square) into Notepad it will be the correct character.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unicode (wide) version of FindWindow and use wide strings for the search.  I also recommend saving the source in UTF-8 encoding and using the `/utf-8` compiler switch for the Microsoft compiler; otherwise, the compiler will assume a localized ANSI encoding to interpret the wide string.  That's fine if you're localized encoding is a Chinese-variant, but if you're on a US or Western European version of Windows the Microsoft IDE will probably prompt you to save in UTF-16 if you use Chinese characters in string constants:

Example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //HWND h = FindWindowW(NULL,L"马克"); // works if saved in UTF-8 encoding
    //                                    // and compiled with /utf-8.

    HWND h = FindWindowW(NULL,L"\u9a6c\u514b");

    if(h == NULL)
        printf("err = %ld\n",GetLastError());
    else
        printf("handle = %p\n",h);
}
```

On Windows I changed the terminal window to a matching Chinese title with `title 马克` and this code found the window:

```
C:\>title 马克

C:\>test
handle = 00000000000B0258

C:\>test
handle = 00000000000B0258
```

Microsoft's Spy++ tool confirms the handle:
[image: Spy++ data with matching handle]

Comment: i did try this, and the first time i try i use with \x unicode, and it found, but then after that i try again, it always not found, hwnd == null;

Comment: @nelLuffy Update your question with example code of your attempt.  I updated answer with a full example.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I found the issue is my computer locale, i need to change to Taiwan(traditional) for the software able to show the program name properly, and then i will be able to search it via Unicode, if i change back to english or other even china(simplified), it won't found the using unicode. Is this the limit that cannot be go through or do you have solution?

Comment: @nelLuffy wide APIs are locale independent. Are you using wide APIs in all calls?

Comment: it might sound stupid, but what is wide APIs, i edited the question with my code, but worked only change locale to Taiwan(traditional).

Comment: @nelLuffy Wide APIs are the W versions like `FindWindowW` that require wide (wchar_t*) strings or wide constants like `L"马克"` for example.  Your updated question has invalid Unicode code points.  What is the actual text of the window you are trying to find?  Put that in the string, save the file as UTF-8 and use `/utf8` compiler switch.